# ASP.NET web application working incorrectly in IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, cassini

I have an ASP.NET web application that is not working correctly once deployed to IIS 7 on a Windows server 2008 box.  The particular page is using an update panel and hides/shows drop down lists based off of a selection in a drop down list.  The page is working perfectly locally using Cassini (the local webserver used by Visual Studio 2008), but loses the items from the drop downs and does not show and hide the controls upon callbacks from within the update panel.

I've googled around and have a suspicion it may have something to do with the Integrated vs. Classic pipeline in IIS 7.  It's currently using the DefaultAppPool(Integrated). Can someone help me figure out what I should do???

Comment: Can you post the code? Also are you loading the "items" from a DB if so then check for the DB connection.

Comment: I can't post the code, but I am loading these items from a database.  The database connection is fine, but I just lose everything when it does a callback and refreshes the page even though viewstate is turned on.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTTP conversation with a web debugger like Fiddler?  If not, that might offer some clues.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with the version of the .NET framework installed on the server.  It sounds like you're using the ASP.NET AJAX libraries that ship with .NET 3.5.  Windows Server 2008 does not ship with .NET 3.5 by default ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc531167.aspx)).  It has to be installed separately.

Comment: 3.5 is installed on the server and other pages within the site are functioning as expected :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your sites Application Pool - Managed Pipline Mode to "Classic" instead of "Integrated"?  I know in the past I've run into the same sort of problem in IIS7 when running in "Integrated" mode and using the following Url rewriter for my sites: UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that the web application was running under another website whose web.config had set EnableViewstate to 'false' which was causing this child web application to incorrectly function.